# Creating YUM/RPM repositories

Tags: rpm

I'd like to create a standard yum/rpm repository with package signing and whatever other best practices exist.

What is the procedure to add RPM, sign it and update the repo xmls?

Comment: This is good information to get, but the level of depth required to answer such a question has already resulted in dozens of tutorials on the Internets. You'll probably get much better results if you break your question down to its constituent components and ask them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [createrepo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/createrepo) command to do this.

Make a folder containing the files you wish to distribute. Run createrepo.

From there, you can create a .repo file describing the location of the repository. This file would be distributed to the systems that require access to the repository. That's about it.

[Some other notes here.](http://sbr600blog.blogspot.com/2012/03/creating-your-own-custom-yum.html)